# Modify Customer id from Prestashop 1.6.1.2 back end

Tags: php, prestashop, backend, prestashop-1.6, userid

Hello everyone I need to change the back end to give the possibility to modifiy the customer ID without going through the database. Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance...

Any Help ? Just want to do the same done here -> [prestashop forum topic](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/456387-how-to-add-custom-fields-when-creating-a-customer-in-back-office/)

Comment: there is no default functioning in prestashop. I can create a module if you need what do you think?

Comment: con you please give help at this topic -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487896/fetch-data-from-prestashop-custom-field

Comment: As you see I've extended the customer object of prestashop with a new custom field I need to put the values of that custom fields to the array field of that module I shared in that topic and I'm done!

Comment: Anyway any kind of solution will be appreciated

Comment: You need more information ? I'm here to explain as bettere as I can

Comment: im stuck please help

Comment: add me on sky-pe. "developerondemand"

Comment: can't find you on skype any way please help me on this topic because I've extended the prestashop customer object giving a new custom field and making editable the one for customer id but when i trying to save the modified Id it gives error

Comment: send me ur sk-ype name

Comment: can you please take a look a this  -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49507474/put-mysql-query-result-in-array-inside-a-class/49507997?noredirect=1#comment86022312_49507997