# Put Mysql query result in array inside a class

Tags: php, mysql, function, class, scope

Hello everybody again I'm tryin to resolve my issue poste in this topic -> [Fetch data from Prestashop custom field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487896/fetch-data-from-prestashop-custom-field) 
I've have made a MySql query outside my class and now it works but i need to put the result in an array inside the class. I paste my code below:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT codice_target FROM customer";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id_customer"]. " - Codice target: " . $row["codice_target"]."<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Then there is the class and the function i need to put the result from the query

```
class AdvancedExport extends Module
{

//other methods here...

        public function fputToFile($file, $allexportfields, $object, $ae)
        {
            if($allexportfields && $file && $object && $ae)
            {
                //one ready for export product
                $readyForExport = array();


                //put in correct sort order
                foreach ($allexportfields as $value)
                {
                    $object = $this->processDecimalSettings($object, $ae, $value);
                    $readyForExport[$value] = iconv("UTF-8", $ae->charset, $object[$value]);

                }

                // need to put mysql query result here inside $readyForExport['codice_target'];

                $this->counter[$readyForExport['id_order']] = (!empty($this->counter[$readyForExport['id_order']])) ? ++$this->counter[$readyForExport['id_order']] : 1; // try here
                $readyForExport['orderLine'] = $this->counter[$readyForExport['id_order']]; // and try here

                //print_r('The id_order is added: ' . $readyForExport['orderLine']); // see if it is added

                //echo '<pre>' . var_dump($readyForExport) . '</pre>';

                // modifiche === Dario === prezzo
                $newPrice = substr($readyForExport['product_price'], 0, strpos($readyForExport['product_price'], "."));
                $readyForExport['product_price'] = $newPrice;

                // === data

                $newDateAdd = new DateTime($readyForExport['date_add']);
                $readyForExport['date_add'] = $newDateAdd->format('d/m/Y');


                // aggiungo 21 giorni - 3 settimane - alla data di acquisto
                $date_mod = clone $newDateAdd;
                $date_mod->add(new DateInterval('P21D'));
                $readyForExport['delivery_date'] = $date_mod->format('d/m/Y');

                // === data invoice
                $newDateInvoice = clone $newDateAdd;
                $readyForExport['invoice_date'] = $newDateAdd->format('d/m/Y');

                //scambio l'id customer con il codice_target

                //$readyForExport['codice_target'] = 8989;

                $textTarget = (string)$readyForExport['codice_target']; 

                $readyForExport['id_customer'] = $textTarget;

                // aggiungo gli zeri davanti al customer id
                $id_count = strlen($readyForExport['id_customer']);            
                if ($id_count == 1) {

                    $newCustomer = "0000000".$readyForExport['id_customer'];
                    $readyForExport['id_customer'] = $newCustomer;

                }elseif ($id_count == 2) {

                    $newCustomer = "000000".$readyForExport['id_customer'];
                    $readyForExport['id_customer'] = $newCustomer;

                }elseif ($id_count == 3) {

                    $newCustomer = "00000".$readyForExport['id_customer'];
                    $readyForExport['id_customer'] = $newCustomer;

                }elseif ($id_count == 4) {
                    $newCustomer = "0000".$readyForExport['id_customer'];
                    $readyForExport['id_customer'] = $newCustomer;

                }elseif ($id_count == 5) {
                    $newCustomer = "000".$readyForExport['id_customer'];
                    $readyForExport['id_customer'] = $newCustomer;

                }elseif ($id_count == 6) {
                    $newCustomer = "00".$readyForExport['id_customer'];
                    $readyForExport['id_customer'] = $newCustomer;

                }

                // elaboro lo SKU

                $textSku = (string)$readyForExport['product_name']; 

                $newSku_1 = $readyForExport['product_name'];

                $newSku_1 = substr($newSku_1,0,4);
                $newSku_2 = "/".substr($textSku,-4,4);

                $newSku_tot = $newSku_1.$newSku_2; 

                $newSku_tot = str_replace(' ', '', $newSku_tot);
                $newSku_tot = str_replace('-', '', $newSku_tot);
                $newSku_tot = str_replace('co', '', $newSku_tot);

                $newSku_tot = str_replace('e', '', $newSku_tot);
                $newSku_tot = str_replace('r', '', $newSku_tot);

                $readyForExport['product_name'] = $newSku_tot;



                // aggiungo un campo fisso
                $readyForExport['causale'] = "NR";

                // aggiungo un campo fisso
                $readyForExport['ORCL'] = "ORCL";

                //$readyForExport['G'] = "";
                $readyForExport['J'] = "";
                $readyForExport['K'] = "";
                $readyForExport['L'] = "";
                $readyForExport['M'] = "";
                $readyForExport['N'] = "";
                $readyForExport['P'] = "";
                $readyForExport['Q'] = "";
                $readyForExport['R'] = "30";

                $index_arr=array("id_customer","date_add","ORCL","product_name","causale","product_quantity","product_price","delivery_date","id_order","J","K","L","M","N","orderLine","P","Q","R");

                //riordino i campi in base a come li dispongo nella variabile $index_arr
                $arr_t=array();
                foreach($index_arr as $i=>$v) {
                    foreach($readyForExport as $k=>$b) {
                        if ($k==$v) $arr_t[$k]=$b;
                    }
                }
                $readyForExport=$arr_t;

                //write into csv line by line
                fputcsv($file, $readyForExport, $ae->delimiter, $ae->separator);
            }
        }
```

Thanks far all done until now, Im really close to the goal.

Comment: why not just simply call that function after you get the result from the query. you just need to add a new parameter `$result`. Or you create a setter methode in your class an create a private variable which will be changed by it.

Comment: many thanks, it sound cool but I don't have the skill to do that can you help me ?

Comment: I think for this script is better to create a method in the class with the private variable that contains the query result and then put it in $readyForExport['codice_target'] array field

Answer (score 0):

Array values initialized to `$rtoclass` variable outside the class, then passed to an `AdvancedExport` object through its method - $obj->`set_arr_needed( $rtoclass );`

On `$obj->fputToFile()` call, the needed array will automatically be available for use inside it via the variable `$arr_needed_in`.

Try:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT codice_target FROM customer";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$rtoclass = array();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "id: " . $row["id_customer"]. " - Codice target: " . $row["codice_target"]."<br>";
        $rtoclass[] = $row;
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$obj = new AdvancedExport();
$obj->set_arr_needed( $rtoclass );

$conn->close();
```

For the class:

```
class AdvancedExport extends Module
{

        //other methods here...

        private $arr_needed = array(); 

        public function set_arr_needed( $arr ) {    
            $this->arr_needed = $arr;
        }

        public function get_arr_needed() {  
            return $this->arr_needed;
        }

        public function fputToFile($file, $allexportfields, $object, $ae)
        {
            $arr_needed_in = $this->get_arr_needed(); // array needed already inside..

            if($allexportfields && $file && $object && $ae)
            {
                //one ready for export product
                $readyForExport = array();


                //put in correct sort order
                foreach ($allexportfields as $value)
                {
                    $object = $this->processDecimalSettings($object, $ae, $value);
                    $readyForExport[$value] = iconv("UTF-8", $ae->charset, $object[$value]);

                }

                // need to put mysql query result here inside $readyForExport['codice_target'];

                $this->counter[$readyForExport['id_order']] = (!empty($this->counter[$readyForExport['id_order']])) ? ++$this->counter[$readyForExport['id_order']] : 1; // try here
                $readyForExport['orderLine'] = $this->counter[$readyForExport['id_order']]; // and try here

                //print_r('The id_order is added: ' . $readyForExport['orderLine']); // see if it is added

                //echo '<pre>' . var_dump($readyForExport) . '</pre>';

                // modifiche === Dario === prezzo
                $newPrice = substr($readyForExport['product_price'], 0, strpos($readyForExport['product_price'], "."));
                $readyForExport['product_price'] = $newPrice;

                // === data

                $newDateAdd = new DateTime($readyForExport['date_add']);
                $readyForExport['date_add'] = $newDateAdd->format('d/m/Y');


                // aggiungo 21 giorni - 3 settimane - alla data di acquisto
                $date_mod = clone $newDateAdd;
                $date_mod->add(new DateInterval('P21D'));
                $readyForExport['delivery_date'] = $date_mod->format('d/m/Y');

                // === data invoice
                $newDateInvoice = clone $newDateAdd;
                $readyForExport['invoice_date'] = $newDateAdd->format('d/m/Y');

                //scambio l'id customer con il codice_target

                //$readyForExport['codice_target'] = 8989;

                $textTarget = (string)$readyForExport['codice_target']; 

                $readyForExport['id_customer'] = $textTarget;

                // aggiungo gli zeri davanti al customer id
                $id_count = strlen($readyForExport['id_customer']);            
                if ($id_count == 1) {

                    $newCustomer = "0000000".$readyForExport['id_customer'];
                    $readyForExport['id_customer'] = $newCustomer;

                }elseif ($id_count == 2) {

                    $newCustomer = "000000".$readyForExport['id_customer'];
                    $readyForExport['id_customer'] = $newCustomer;

                }elseif ($id_count == 3) {

                    $newCustomer = "00000".$readyForExport['id_customer'];
                    $readyForExport['id_customer'] = $newCustomer;

                }elseif ($id_count == 4) {
                    $newCustomer = "0000".$readyForExport['id_customer'];
                    $readyForExport['id_customer'] = $newCustomer;

                }elseif ($id_count == 5) {
                    $newCustomer = "000".$readyForExport['id_customer'];
                    $readyForExport['id_customer'] = $newCustomer;

                }elseif ($id_count == 6) {
                    $newCustomer = "00".$readyForExport['id_customer'];
                    $readyForExport['id_customer'] = $newCustomer;

                }

                // elaboro lo SKU

                $textSku = (string)$readyForExport['product_name']; 

                $newSku_1 = $readyForExport['product_name'];

                $newSku_1 = substr($newSku_1,0,4);
                $newSku_2 = "/".substr($textSku,-4,4);

                $newSku_tot = $newSku_1.$newSku_2; 

                $newSku_tot = str_replace(' ', '', $newSku_tot);
                $newSku_tot = str_replace('-', '', $newSku_tot);
                $newSku_tot = str_replace('co', '', $newSku_tot);

                $newSku_tot = str_replace('e', '', $newSku_tot);
                $newSku_tot = str_replace('r', '', $newSku_tot);

                $readyForExport['product_name'] = $newSku_tot;



                // aggiungo un campo fisso
                $readyForExport['causale'] = "NR";

                // aggiungo un campo fisso
                $readyForExport['ORCL'] = "ORCL";

                //$readyForExport['G'] = "";
                $readyForExport['J'] = "";
                $readyForExport['K'] = "";
                $readyForExport['L'] = "";
                $readyForExport['M'] = "";
                $readyForExport['N'] = "";
                $readyForExport['P'] = "";
                $readyForExport['Q'] = "";
                $readyForExport['R'] = "30";

                $index_arr=array("id_customer","date_add","ORCL","product_name","causale","product_quantity","product_price","delivery_date","id_order","J","K","L","M","N","orderLine","P","Q","R");

                //riordino i campi in base a come li dispongo nella variabile $index_arr
                $arr_t=array();
                foreach($index_arr as $i=>$v) {
                    foreach($readyForExport as $k=>$b) {
                        if ($k==$v) $arr_t[$k]=$b;
                    }
                }
                $readyForExport=$arr_t;

                //write into csv line by line
                fputcsv($file, $readyForExport, $ae->delimiter, $ae->separator);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167683/discussion-on-answer-by-karlo-kokkak-put-mysql-query-result-in-array-inside-a-cl).